# How to return all matching values without duplicates into one cell in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm stuck trying to vlookup multiples values duplicates and return all match into one cell.

I would like to convert with formulas a sheet like this:

| Name | Product |
| --- | --- |
| James | Peach |
| James | Apple |
| James | Cherry |
| Andy | Banana |
| Wallace | Peach |
| Wallace | Cherry |
| Mike | Banana |

On a new sheet like this:

| Name | Product |
| --- | --- |
| James | Peach,Apple,Cherry |
| Andy | Banana |
| Wallace | Peach,Cherry |
| Mike | Banana |

[Here is an example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z7S58GnykkFriL35729Ua-yh-4ih1ZxfpRsuxjgoQdg/edit#gid=2062344380)

Edit: I forgot to specify it, but the result should be in a new tab, like a vlookup

I have not found a functional solution in my research, [here is the post](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2706-excel-vlookup-return-multiple-values-in-one-cell.html) that seems to come closest to my need. But the proposed formula does not work: **=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF($A$2:$A$11=E2,$C$2:$C$11,""))**

Do you have any idea how I can solve this formula? Your help will be greatly appreciated. I'm going in a loop and I can't find a solution :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
=JOIN(", ";FILTER(B:B;A:A=E2;B:B<>""))
```

Or for the whole column:

```
=byrow(E2:E;lambda(each;if(each="";"";join(", ";filter(B:B;A:A=each;B:B<>"")))))
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but I am sorry, I forgot to mention it but as the spreadsheet example, I would like to have to output in a dedicated tab, like a vlookup

I just tried to edit your suggestion but I get an error:

=byrow(A2:A;lambda(each;IF(each="";"";join(", ";filter(=Input!B2:B;=Input!A2:A=each;=Input!B2:B<>"")))))

Comment: =byrow(A2:A;lambda(each;IF(each="";"";join(", ";filter(Input!B2:B;Input!A2:A=each;Input!B2:B<>"")))))

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=LAMBDA(x; {UNIQUE(FILTER(x; x<>""))\BYROW(UNIQUE(FILTER(x; x<>"")); 
 LAMBDA(a; TEXTJOIN(", "; 1; FILTER(OFFSET(x;;1); x=a))))})
 (Input!A2:INDEX(Input!A:A; MAX(ROW(Input!A:A)*(Input!A:A<>""))))
```

[image]